# Optional parameter of class in typescript

Tags: typescript

given following code:

```
class ConnectionOptions
{
    host: string = "localhost";
    port: number = 5672;
    username: string = "guest";
    password: string = "guest";
}

class ConnectorClass
{
    options: ConnectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();

    SetOptions(options: ConnectionOptions)
    {
        console.log(options);
        this.options = options;
    }
}

// Adopt singleton pattern
var Connector = (function () {
    var instance : ConnectorClass;

    function createInstance() {
        return new ConnectorClass();
    }
 
    return {
        I: function () : ConnectorClass {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

// TestApp
Connector.I().SetOptions({ 'host': "192.168.17.5" });
```

In the last line there is following typescript error:

```
index.ts:50:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ host: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConnectionOptions'.
  Type '{ host: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ConnectionOptions': port, username, password

50 Connector.I().SetOptions({ 'host': "192.168.17.5" });
```

I understand why the error is thrown: TS is expecting 4 properties but I only want to set 1 of them, isnt this possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code, an interface seems more suitable than a class. You have several classes implementing the interface if required. Then, if you want some of arguments to be optional, you may use the optional modifier (`?`):

```js
interface ConnectionOptions {
    host?: string;
    port?: number;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
}

const DefaultConnectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5672,
  username: 'guest',
  password: 'guest',
}
```

Now your `SetOptions` method can look something like this:

```js
    options: ConnectionOptions = DefaultConnectionOptions;

    SetOptions(options: ConnectionOptions) {
        console.log(options);
        this.options = { ...DefaultConnectionOptions, ...options };
    }
```

Your call `Connector.I().SetOptions({ 'host': "192.168.17.5" });` should now work because no property is mandatory.

---

It may be that you want all connection options to be mandatory, but when calling `SetOptions` they are not mandatory. In that case **do not use** the optional modifier on the properties. Change your `SetOptions` signature to use `Partial<T>` instead:

```js
    SetOptions(options: Partial<ConnectionOptions>) {
        console.log(options);
        this.options = { ...DefaultConnectionOptions, ...options };
    }
```

The above will still force `this.options` to have every single property, but the argument `options` does not have to provide all properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine! Can u maybe explain why a class is not the best option here? I came from C#, in where I would have done this 100% with a class.#

Comment: In typescript, a wide-spread pattern is to code for interfaces. Then have implementations for the interface as required. This makes the code - in general - more flexible because the focus is not in the implementation (there are articles on this pattern that can further explain). Also, the wide use of  anonymous objects in javascript (`{ host: 'localhost' }`) can be more easily supported with interfaces (instead of having to do `SetOptions(new ConnectionOptions(....))`)